# How to convert sync calls to Async call of WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

At present we have a couple of WCF service. They are called sysnchronously as follows,

```
XYZ.XYZClient test= new XYZ.XYZClient();
bool result = test.Add(1,2);
```

Can someone explain me how we can convert this onto a Async call?

Comment: Check the link: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=237. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059(v=vs.110).aspx).

It would become:

```
double value1 = 100.00D;
double value2 = 15.99D;
XYZ.XYZClient test= new XYZ.XYZClient();
test.AddCompleted += new EventHandler<AddCompletedEventArgs>(AddCallback);
test.AddAsync(1, 2);
Console.WriteLine("Add({0},{1})", value1, value2);
```

**Event args for the operation**

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
public partial class AddCompletedEventArgs : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs
{
    private object[] results;

    public AddCompletedEventArgs(object[] results, System.Exception exception, bool cancelled, object userState) : 
            base(exception, cancelled, userState)
    {       this.results = results;         }

    public double Result
    {
        get            {
            base.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary();
            return ((double)(this.results[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

**Code that executes on completion**

```
// Asynchronous callbacks for displaying results.
static void AddCallback(object sender, AddCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add Result: {0}", e.Result);
}
```

**Delegate**

```
public event System.EventHandler<AddCompletedEventArgs> AddCompleted;
```

Comment: what is `AddCompletedEventArgs` and `AddCallback` here ?

Comment: `AddCompletedEventArgs` is an event handler and `AddCallback1` is a call back method that is handled when it completes. I will add that to the answer.

Comment: And `AddCompleted` is a method?

Comment: @user2729272 It is a delegate i.e. `public event System.EventHandler<AddCompletedEventArgs> AddCompleted;`

Comment: I understand the client service call part. Now I would Like to know where the delegate, code after completion and Event args operation blocks to be written?

Answer (score 0):

Change your wcf-proxies to generate task-based operations and use async/await.

```
XYZ.XYZClient test= new XYZ.XYZClient(); 
bool result = await test.AddAsync(1, 2);
```

[image: Service Reference Settings]